# Need help with using nested If expressions in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, conditional

Questions regarding the use of nested For-loops have been posted a few times on StackExchange. However, I think that the solutions to those questions are not really applicable to what I am trying to do here. I am trying to use nested For-loops in `NDSolve`, which somehow does not work.

One of the methods included in the solution to other similar problems include things like putting `If` in `Which`. That does not seem to work for me.

My code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
z[t_] := y[t] - l Cos[φ[t]];
n[t_] := k Abs[z[t]]^(3/2) - c z'[t];
R = 0.0238;
k = 141000000;
c = 20;
g = 9.81;
μk = 0.1804;
i = 8.92958*10^-6;
m = 0.035;
l = R Sqrt[2 (1 + Sin[(1/2) π - 2*0.41])];
a = 
  NDSolve[
    {m y''[t] == n[t] - m g, 
     φ''[t] == (n[t]*l*Sin[φ[t]] + m x''[t]*l*Cos[φ[t]])/i, 
     x''[t] == 
       If[(x[t] - l*φ[t] == 0) // Evaluate, 
         l (φ''[t] Cos[φ[t]] - φ'[t]^2 Sin[φ[t]]) // Evaluate, 
         If[x[t] - l*φ[t] > 0, -μk*n[t]/m // Evaluate, -μk*n[t]/m // Evaluate]], 
     y[0] == l*Cos[0.41], y'[0] == -2.22, 
     φ[0] == 0.41, φ'[0] == -50, 
     x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[z[t] == 0 // Evaluate, 
       "StopIntegration"; Print[y'[t]]; Print[φ'[t]]]}, 
    {y'[t], y[t], x[t], x'[t], φ[t], φ'[t], z[t], n[t], φ''[t]}, 
    {t, 0, 0.2}, 
    Method -> 
      {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
       "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, 
    WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, 
    MaxSteps -> 100000000, 
    PrecisionGoal -> Automatic]
```

The piece of code containing the nested `If` is

```
x''[t] == 
  If[(x[t] - l*φ[t] == 0) // Evaluate, 
    l (φ''[t] Cos[φ[t]] - φ'[t]^2 Sin[φ[t]]) // Evaluate, 
    If[x[t] - l*φ[t] > 0, -μk*n[t]/m // Evaluate, -μk*n[t]/m // Evaluate]],
```

It would be great if anyone can help.

#### Edit

I am trying to simulate a bounce of an object through this equation. I have the equation describing the motion along the y axis, x axis and rotation respectively. However, for the motion along the x-axis, it would be piecewise as during the collision, there may be both static friction and kinetic friction. I have to take both into account. Under kinetic friction, it will be either in the positive or negative direction depending on the relative motion between contact point and ground. That's why there are nested `If` expressions. The outer `If` is to differentiate between static and kinetic friction, while the inner `If` is to differentiate between positive and negative kinetic friction.

Comment: It would be helpful if before posting the code you formulate in words the problem you are going to solve with this code. If this is NDSolve, it should be a differential equation. Just formulate it. Describe, (either in words, or as a formula) why there should be conditional operators inside.

Comment: I have edited the post. Thanks

Comment: I don't think those calls to `Evaluate` are doing you any good. Read the **Possible Issues** section of the documentation article for [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html).

Comment: Have you seen Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/NDSolve/Applications/Hybrid Differential Equations?

Comment: Yes I just took a look. Maybe `WhenEvent` is a good way, but I think it will come with a lot of limitation as well because lets say when the `WhenEvent` condition is satisfied, it will go from the first state to the second state. But What if the condition is satisfied again later on in the simulation, and i need mathematica to transit from the second state back to the first state. Can `WhenEvent` do that? @AlexeiBoulbitch

Comment: @m_goldberg I see. The evaluate in the nested `If` is not doing its job. Is that what's happening here? May I know how to solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `z[t]` and therefore `n[t]` depend on `phi` and `y`, but that dependence is internal and not explicit. E.g. the simplified code, something like which happens at the initial condition when `NDSolve` starts integrating, `If[x[t] == 0, n[t], 2 n[t]] /. t -> 0 /. {x[0] -> 0, y[0] -> 0.0400369, \[CurlyPhi][0] -> 0.41}` does not result in a number. The best solution is to rewrite `z` and `n`, e.g. `z[y_, phi_] := y - l Cos[phi]` and similarly for `n[y_, phi_] := ...`; then use `n[y[t], phi[t]]` in the equations. Then all the `Evaluate`s are unnecessary, as @m_goldberg suggests in the comments. The quick fix is to put an `Evaluate` on the nested `If`:

```
NDSolve[{m y''[t] == 
   n[t] - m g, φ''[
    t] == (n[t]*l*Sin[φ[t]] + 
      m x''[t]*l*Cos[φ[t]])/i, 
  x''[t] == 
   If[(x[t] - l*φ[t] == 0) // Evaluate, 
    l (φ''[
          t] Cos[φ[t]] - φ'[t]^2 Sin[φ[
           t]]) // Evaluate, 
    Evaluate@
     If[x[t] - l*φ[t] > 0, -μk*n[t]/m // 
       Evaluate, -μk*n[t]/m // Evaluate]], y[0] == l*Cos[0.41], 
  y'[0] == -2.22, φ[0] == 0.41, φ'[0] == -50, 
  x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
  WhenEvent[z[t] == 0 // Evaluate, "StopIntegration"(*;Print[y'[t]];
   Print[φ'[t]]*)]},
 {y'[t], y[t], x[t], x'[t], φ[t], φ'[t], z[t], 
  n[t], φ''[t]}, {t, 0, 0.2}, 
 Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
   "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}, AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, 
 WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, MaxSteps -> 100000000, 
 PrecisionGoal -> Automatic]
```

Probably such a complicated problem has other issues.  Certainly `x[t] - l*φ[t] == 0` is probably never going to be `True` due to the discrete nature of numerical integration. It is given a special semantics in `WhenEvent[x[t] - l*φ[t] == 0,...]` but not in `If[x[t] - l*φ[t] == 0, <one>, <two>]`. The `If` variant is equivalent to simply `<two>` with a very high probability.  So @bob_the_legend's comment concerning refactoring the `If`s with `WhenEvent` seems worth pursuing.

But to reiterate, I'd say the starting point is to follow good programming practice and make all parameters a function depends on be explicit arguments to the function.